# Pass parameter to Azure Data Factory-ADF activity based on trigger

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, databricks, azure-data-factory

I have Azure Data pipeline where I have to pass a parameter to Databricks activity. I have multiple Event based triggers (Updation of blob folder) added for that activity. When specific trigger gets activated, it should pass a parameter to Databricks activity and based on that notebook should run. Is there any way to pass parameter from Event based trigger to Databricks notebook activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger gives out 2 parameters.

- @triggerBody().fileName
- @triggerBody().folderPath

You will have to add this to JSON code of trigger

```
        "parameters": {
            "FPath": "@triggerBody().folderPath"
        }
```

Use this parameter as Pipeline variable `@triggerBody().FPath` and use that variable with other activities. Please refer to link below for detailed explanation

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6063/create-event-based-trigger-in-azure-data-factory/

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Comment: @Nikhil  @triggerBody().filenae is only available for first activity, is there any way I can get it on second activity in a pipeline

Comment: @BrijanElwadhi: As mentioned in the answer. Assign triggerBody().fileName to pipeline parameter which you should be able to use anywhere in pipeline.